# Can MongoDBs full text search be used with Spring Data REST?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-rest

I just started playing around with Spring Data Rest and wanted to expose a finder for a field which is text indexed in MongoDB. I have the following index definition:

```
@TextIndexed
private String title;
```

and verified that the index is created. I have created a finder method on the repository definition:

```
public interface ContentRespository extends MongoRepository<Content, String> {
    public Page<Content> findByTitle(@Param("title") TextCriteria title, @Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
}
```

By calling the REST API URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/contents/search/findByTitle?title=test
```

I get the following error:

```
2017-01-19 13:16:41.831 ERROR 16705 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.support.QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert test into org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.TextCriteria!] with root cause

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param  org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.TextCriteria]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
....
```

What would be the correct way to call the REST API? I can't find any documentation about it. Or how would it be possible to write a converter for TextCriteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I came back to this and found the answer by defining a finder with a @Query notation:

```
@Query("{$text: {$search: ?0}}")
public Page<Content> findByTitle(@Param("title") String title, @Param("pageable") Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to mongo - but spring rest says you that it can not convert incoming string ( from you web request )   to exposed method parameter.   You have 2 options - create and register converter or wrap method in question  and convert strings to required types yourself

Comment: yes, is there any example how to write such converter?

Comment: Sure. Google will help to find it. But wrapping content repository by some class would be easier

Comment: sure, I can google it, but my question was more about the default way to access a _TextIndexed_ field via the REST API. Other finder methods for _Indexed_ fields are working out of the box. Writing a converter would be the second option

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html  -  part about registering custom property editors is a good start.